# Error removing subsite from collection in SharePoint online 2013

Tags: sharepoint-online

I'm getting the following error when trying to remove a subsite from site collection.

```
Remove-SPOSite : The managed path [subsitename] is not a managed path in this tenant.
```

I've checked the managed path for the tenant using a script and the results are

```
https://mysite.sharepoint.com/[subsitename]/test
```

So my resulting code for powershell is

```
Remove-SPOSite https://mysite.sharepoint.com/[subsitename]/test
```

I suspect the managed paths has gone screwie somewhere but I cannot see where! Any suggestions would be most helpful.

Does sharepoint online do something I cannot see on the managed paths?  I.e `https://mysite.sharepoint.com/sites/athletesub/test`but hides the sites part of the URI?

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out.

Someone created a subsite within the subsite of test!  As the error message didn't give me that info I missed it.

Thanks